# Support for POSTing XML in HttpUnit?

Tags: java, xml, junit

Does [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) support getting a response from an HTTP POST with an xml argument?

**Edit**

If you want to send a post request, you might instantiate a PostMethodWebRequest object.

```
WebRequest request = new PostMethodWebRequest("http://example.com/thing/create");
```

And if you want to set parameters for that request, I *think* what you would do is this:

```
request.setParameter("attribute", "value");
```

But what I am looking for is how to make the *body* of the post an XML document that holds the data for all the attributes I need to create a new Thing. Does anyone know the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you be more clear? Whats do you mean by xml argument?

Comment: Sorry to be vague. I had to navigate through more of the HttpUnit documentation before I could explain myself. I have posted an edit of my question with some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
InputStream body = new FileInputStream("create.xml");
WebRequest request = new PostMethodWebRequest("http://example.com/thing/create", body, "text/xml");
```